# Customize macOS's Dock with a Bash script

Tags: bash, macos, dock

I want to customize macOS's Dock with a Bash script (without AppleScript).

Currently I have the code (taken and modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637792)):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

defaults delete com.apple.dock persistent-apps

dock_item() {
    printf '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>%s</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>', "$1"
}

defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array \
    "$(dock_item /Applications/iTerm.app)" \
    "$(dock_item /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app)" \
    "$(dock_item /Applications/Slack.app)" \
    "$(dock_item /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app)" \
    "$(dock_item /System/Applications/Utilities/Screenshot.app)"

killall Dock
```

Which changes the default Dock:

[image: default Dock]

To:

[image: resulted Dock]

But I also want it to remove the Downloads folder next to the Trash bin and the duplicated icons  that appear between the vertical lines (in this case only iTerm) of the running applications which are kept/saved in the Dock (to the left of the vertical lines). Like this:

[image: expected Dock]

---

Also, the way the Dock gets updated by the code after the changes are made is by killing the Dock processes which is then automatically restarted. I feel like there should be a faster way to do it that doesn't animate the Dock going down, then the desktop turning black for a moment, opening any minimized applications and then animate the Dock going up ([recording](https://i.imgur.com/lh9tEsY.mp4)).

Comment: The comma in the `printf` format string argument will be included verbatim in the output, even though it's outside the quotes. The argument separator in shell scripts is simply any (unquoted, unescaped) horizontal whitespace. Quoting is generally optional (`ls .` is exactly equivalent to `'ls' '.'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing what `defaults read com.apple.dock` prints before and after manually removing the icons from the Dock I noticed that I just have to delete the `recent-apps` (for the duplicated icons) and `persistent-others` (for the folder) keys as well:

```sh
defaults delete com.apple.dock recent-apps
defaults delete com.apple.dock persistent-others
```